# Find if number went back in same column in SQL

Tags: sql

Looking for support to find if number went back to the previous number in same ID for same column.

Below is example of the data set.

```
ID      Number  Date        Sequence Count
10000B1 60      28.10.2015  10
10000B1 57      28.09.2015  9
10000B1 58      28.08.2015  8
10000B1 57      29.07.2015  7
10000B1 56      30.06.2015  6
10000B1 55      01.05.2015  5
10000B1 54      05.04.2015  4
10000B1 53      06.03.2015  3
10000B1 52      08.02.2015  2
10000B1 51      09.01.2015  1
```

I would like to find exceptions if in same ID, Number went back again to the previous number.

For example: Number  Sequence count 7 with number 57 and again on 9 sequence count the number is 57.

or Number in the Same Column went back to 57 from 58 instead of 59.

Could you please support me in SQL to find these type of cases using SQL?

thanks.
Ravi

Comment: Repeated numbers can be found through group by clause. but please explain what do you mean by "Could you please support me in SQL to find these type of cases using SQL?". DO you have some other problems too??

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from Apple t
where exists (select 1
              from Apple t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.number = t.number and
                    t2.sequence < t.sequence
             );
```

Comment: Could you please give column reference in the code. You can use table as  name 'Apple'.?

Comment: this code is working but its not giving me results what I am looking for. I just want to see if number repeat or went back to previous number.

Comment: @user1045369 . . . This should provide all examples where a number repeats.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle to show what is actually happening?

Comment: its should show ID in which Number is increasing when sequence is decreasing. this is not working.

Comment: @user1045369 . . . (1) Your question is about numbers increasing when the sequence is decreasing.  Don't change the question in a comment.  (2) This will return repeats that are later in the list, regardless of whether the list is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: I have already repeated in my data set. Can we only focus on Number 49? so if number 49 turn back to 48?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select a.* from your_table as a 
inner join your_table as b on a.date > b.date and a.number < b.number
```

With your column name

```
 a.ID, a.`Number`, a.`Date`, a.`Sequence Count`
 from from apple_table as a 
 inner join apple_table as b on a.`Date` > b.`Date` and a.`number` < b.`number`
```

for number and sequence should be

```
 a.ID, a.`Number`, a.`Date`, a.`Sequence Count`
 from from apple_table as a 
 inner join apple_table as b on a.`Sequence Count` < b.`Sequence Count` and a.`number` > b.`number`
```

Comment: Could you please give column reference in the code. You can use table as  name 'Apple'.?

Comment: I have update the answer with the column reference and apple_table for table .. hope is clear

Comment: this code is working but its not giving me results what I am looking for. I just want to see if number repeat or went back to previous number.

Comment: Code should show ID's in which Number is increasing when sequence is decreasing. this is not working.

Comment: I have update the answer with check on Sequece Count and not on date .. hope useful